# How do I make a new table where the rows are based on the entries in another table?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet (given to me, so I don't control the format) that tells me which 3 fruits people like, e.g.,

```
Name     Fruit1     Fruit2     Fruit3
Alice    apple      banana     orange
Bob      apple      pear       plum
Cate     banana     pear       plum
...
```

How can I automatically generate a table where the fruits become the rows, like this?

```
Fruit    Name1     Name2      Name3  ...
apple    Alice     Bob
banana   Alice     Cate
orange   Alice
pear     Bob       Cate
plum     Bob       Cate
```

I'm sure there is just a name for this operation, but I don't know what it is, and haven't figured out the right search to reveal it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure on the best method here. You could first start looking up the array formula to extract the distinct fruits from columns B, C, D. So, maybe put that formula in column F so you now have all the distinct fruits in column F. That's the easy part. Next, you'll need the formula to find which name(s) like each fruit. That will likely be an array formula using "index", "match" and perhaps "if" logic.

Comment: But maybe look at why you need it laid out this way, and perhaps there's a better way to accomplish your end goal. For example, maybe just have the distinct fruits as rows, and the distinct names as columns. Then each cell in your grid would be a countif formula, which would return a "1" if that person likes the fruit, or a 0 if they don't.

Comment: Perhaps try to use an auxiliary table to restructure the data. Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerQuery to solve this problem:

```
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"Name", type text}, {"Fruit 1", type text}, {"Fruit 2", type text}, {"Fruit 3", type text}}),
    #"Entpivotierte andere Spalten" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Geänderter Typ", {"Name"}, "FruitNo", "Fruit"),
    #"Gruppierte Zeilen" = Table.Group(#"Entpivotierte andere Spalten", {"Fruit"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Name=nullable text, FruitNo=text, Fruit=text]}}),
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte" = Table.AddColumn(#"Gruppierte Zeilen", "Benutzerdefiniert", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count], "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)),
    #"Entfernte Spalten" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte",{"Count"}),
    #"Erweiterte Benutzerdefiniert" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Entfernte Spalten", "Benutzerdefiniert", {"Name", "Index"}, {"Name", "Index"}),
    #"Pivotierte Spalte" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Erweiterte Benutzerdefiniert", {{"Index", type text}}, "de-DE"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Erweiterte Benutzerdefiniert", {{"Index", type text}}, "de-DE")[Index]), "Index", "Name")
in
    #"Pivotierte Spalte"
```

[image]